# Need a Hello World example in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

In Eclipse, it's easy, I just need to add a class and tick into something like `Add public static void main()` then run. But with IntelliJ IDEA I can't find how to create a simple "Hello World" project, the run button (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>) is always grayed out even after I added a main class in `Edit Configurations`. In fact, my JAVA background is not good and I am also a newbie to IntelliJ IDEA. So I am thankful to someone who show me a way to start.

Thank in advance.

p/s : I started with a Java Module project, import JDK 6.0, I didn't choose any technology. Then I created a package and a class under `src\`. I saw a TUT video on youtube that there even has a make `main()` command with right click on the class name but I can't find it anywhere. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 11 in 30 days evaluation.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information; if you've set up a run configuration and identified the main class it should be easy. You can also right-click in the class itself and run from there; this should create a run configuration automatically.

Comment: @Dave Newton, I started with a Java Module project, import JDK 6.0, I didn't choose any technology. Then I created a package and a class under `src\ `. I saw a TUT video on youtube that there is even a make `main()` command with right click on the class name but I can't find it anywhere. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 11 in 30 days evaluation.

Comment: When you right-click there's no "Run..." selection in the popup? Do you have a JDK defined?

Comment: I find out that the cause is I miss `String[] args` parameter in the `main()` so it couldn't run. Thank you.

Comment: FYI, IntelliJ IDEA 12 has "Hello world" ready application in the box.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is a transcript of how I just created a Hello World in IDEA 10.5.2 on mac. It should be exactly the same on Windows or Linux.

(you  might wanna jump to step 10)

1. On the startup screen choose **Create New Project**
2. On the next **Create project from scratch**
3. Give a name **HelloStack** and a folder **/tmp/src/HelloStack**
4. **Create Module** is already checked and should be so. The name is predefined to the same as the project and that is fine.
5. Just click **Next** and **Finish** on the rest of the screens. No technologies are needed.
6. If the Project tab isn't open, open it now. It's on the left
7. Under HelloStack there is a folder named src, it's marked in blue meaning that it is a source folder. Right click it and choose **New -> Java Class**. For this simple project we'll skip packages entirly. Name the class something, mine is **HelloStack** like the project and module.
8. Now create a `public static void main`-method, there is a live template for this, just type `psvm` and press tab, it will expand to a complete main method.
9. Another live template is System.out.println, just type `sout` and press tab. Write something.
10. Right click inside the main method, choose **Run "HelloStack.main()"**. This will create a runner, make the code, and run the method (class). From now on there is a runner for this and you can press the green arrow to run it.
11. Done.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thank you very much. Thanks for the `psvm` template, I find out that the cause is I miss `String[] args` parameter in the `main()` so it couldn't run.

Answer (score 5):

There is a very clearly tutorial article for beginners.

http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_and_running_your_first_Java_application

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/creating-running-and-packaging-your-first-java-application.html

Comment: Second link is dead